# MS Project 2013: Can I avoid MSP auto-changing my assignment units to less than 100%?

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2013, resources

Curious if there is a way to avoid Microsoft Project auto-adjusting the assignment units, when I add a resource in the Resource name column.

In the project settings all resources are set to 100% availability and all tasks are set to fixed units.

Basically, I'd like to have a resource always enter with 100% assignment, even for tasks that are less than 8hrs, as it currently auto-adjusts the assignment based on the percentage of the workday, that the work estimate is - see below example.

I can manually adjust the assignment back to 100%, but for huge projects, this is really annoying.

Is there any way to override this?

[image: assignment units]

Answer (score 2):

The screen shot does not show the field names, but it appears that you have a task ***Duration*** of 1 day (e.g. 8 hours), but ***Work*** set to 4 hrs (e.g. half a day). In order for resources to only work 4 hours on an 8 hour task, they must be set at 50%.

Comment: Thanks, Rachel, that is probably what happens. However, as I'm using fixed  unit setting (and not fixed duration), for tasks where work units exceed 8 hours, the duration is extended, and I'd expect that for tasks shorter than, the duration should be dynamically set to less than 1 day (0,5;0,4;0,3, etc.) keeping the resource availability intact, but alas, seems like a build-in logic in Microsoft Project.